# Does anyone know if the D400 is coming out at all and if it is, when is it coming out?

Tags: nikon

I'm looking into buying an upgrade from my D90, and I'm considering the D7000 but also considering holding back for the D400.

Does anyone know if the D400 is coming out at all, and if it is, when?

Thanks for any update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some of Nikon's employees in their camera and marketing departments, and perhaps some friends, family, and business partners know when the D400 is coming out. Release dates, or even the existence of future products, are often closely guarded secrets in the camera industry, even if they're often predictable.

That said, Nikon-following blogger Thom Hogan [guesses we won't see a replacement for the D300s (presumably called the D400) until 2012](http://bythom.com/2011%20Nikon%20News.htm): (see the section "Still Coming")

> FWIW, here's where I stand in expectations at the moment:
>
> - D4 announce unknown, ship around end of year (Dec/Jan/Feb).
> - D700 replacement announce soon (Sept), ship late in year.
> - D300s replacement I don't expect until 2012.
> - Mirrorless I expect to be announced in September, ship soon thereafter.

So, whether it's worthwhile to go for the D7000 now, or save your money and hope the D400 comes out soon is entirely up to you. Keep in mind that the D7000 is still a fantastic camera regardless of whether the D400 exists.

If you can afford more than the D7000 right now, keep in mind that there are other ways to spend your money than on a more expensive body alone: spend the difference on a new (or used) lens, the fastest SD cards you can buy, a vertical grip, or a nice tripod and head.

Or, you could do the “responsible” thing and spend less money on this ridiculous hobby.

Comment: + 1 for the patience and sheer common sense